# Determining line-to-line vs line-to-neutral loads in split-phase panel

Tags: current, calculation, split-phase

I have a split-phase sub-panel, with two 120V legs (red/black) and middle neutral (white). Given Hall-effect current sensor clamps around some combination of red/black/white going into the sub-panel, is it possible to answer the following questions:

- Current between red and white
- Current between black and white
- Current between red and black

For example, if I have 3 amperes being drawn from 120V tools on the red leg, 5 amperes being drawn from 120V tools on the black leg, and 7 amperes being drawn by 240V tools red-to-black, I would have the following possible read-outs from the Hall-effect sensors:

- Red:   3 + 7 = 10 amps
- Black: 5 + 7 = 12 amps
- White: 5 - 3 = 2 amps

Can I get from these numbers back to the three distinct loads?

Comment: No. You would get the same readings with e.g.  1A on Red, 3A on black, and 9A at 240V.

Comment: @BrianDrummond  Can you give more detailed explanation?

Comment: Work through the counterexample and compare it with your example. That one counterexample should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to know what the actual loads are.

If you have a single 10A 240VAC load, there will be zero current on neutral. If you have two 10A 120VAC loads, one on each phase, the neutral wire coming to your house would have zero current flowing in this case too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Any of the new digital power meters will provide all off that information, plus much more, i.e. peaks, minimums, real, apparent, reactive energy, power factor, etc.  Check with a company like Veris Industries who specializes in power monitoring.  They have lower cost, easy to install products, like the E2X Flex series.  Then, if interested in purchasing, check with a rep like Kele.com, who discounts very well.  You can integrate the information using industry standard protocols, or purchase a protocol converter to meet your needs.

Comment: Given the setup in the question, by measuring the two phases and the neutral, the information about individual loads being single or dual phase is not available. This seems like product advertisement.